Deciphering a Medieval Latin text in blackletter


I found some manuscripts that seem to be Medieval Latin, written in blackletter. I tried to decipher it but there are some complicated glyphs that are hard to read.
What I could read are:

Tam seva(?) aut(em?) illa pestis fuisse fertur que ...ĩes in via in mensa inludis subito sternuntando moreventur.


Unde eum aliquis sternuntantem audiebat vix(?) ... auxilium dicebat ad...d(en?)s et sp(?)... exalabat.


Tamdem p... stragem ...ĩm maximam ... ...nia et pinnas(?) graves ... processional... eunti p... ... eum ...sa plebe et clero(?) apparet angelus sanguino lenaĩ(?) ensem ...agina veponens(?) ... pala... magi(s?)

Could anyone please help me with it?

This is a passage from the Legenda aurea cap. 66. I can make out part of it. with expansions and "corrections" to classical orthography, it reads:
Tam saeva autem illa pestis fuit, ut homines in via, in mensa, in ludis subito sternutando morerentur, unde, cum aliquis, sternutantem audiebat, vix ...

Here's a digital version of a 19th century edition, but note that the edition doesn't have all the same readings as your manuscript. This is probably a case of multiple manuscript traditions.
https://www.loc.gov/resource/gdcmassbookdig.legendaaureavulg00jaco/?st=gallery

@Kingshorsey That would be a good answer!

@Kingshorsey Gratias ago for your detailed information!

This appears to be the Belles Heures of Jean, Duke of Berry.  I have some notes about deciphering it on my blog, in connection with a different page of the same manuscript.  Wikipedia also has an article about it: scribal abbreviation.  For example, a circumflex on a vowel represents an omitted 'm', and a tilde represents an omitted 'n'.

The Metropolitan Museum of Art has an illustrated book about the Belles Heures, called The Art of Illumination.  It is available for free download, and provides transcriptions and translations of the Latin, as well as many other details.  Your excerpts, are explained on pages 138–139.

@MJD Thanks for your follow-up information!

Here's my transcription (with some help from this transcription, which I came across after getting most of the words):

Tam saeva autem illa pestis fuisse fertur quod homines in via in
mensa in ludis subito sternutando morerentur.
Unde cum aliquis sternutantem audiebat vix in eius
auxilium dicebat adiuvet te deus et spiritum exhalabat.

My translation:

But that plague is said to have been so severe that men suddenly died sneezing on the road, at the table, and at their games. This is why, when someone heard another sneezing, no sooner did he say in his aid, "God help you," that he [i.e. the other] breathed out his spirit.

Second excerpt:

Tandem post stragem hominum maximam, luctus, ieiunia, et
poenitentias graves, papae processionaliter eunti per Romam cum
universa plebe et clero apparet angelus sangino-
lentum ensem in vagina reponens supra palatium magis[tri?].

My translation:

Finally, after a very great carnage of men, weepings, fastings, and grave penances, an angel appears to the pope going in procession through Rome with the whole people and clergy, [the angel was] putting a bloody sword back in [its] scabbard over the palace of the magistrate.


@IlyaDaskevics Thanks! I'm confused what a "palatium magicum" could possibly mean in this context, and the sign after mag (which is also printed in the note you mentioned) is the "9" sign, which usually stands for "us" (as in eius above), though it can also stand for is, os, and s.

For the first excerpt, the Metropolitan Museum's book about the Belles Heures suggests (p.138) "Whenever one heard someone sneezing there was hardly time to respond to him with, ‘God bless thee!’ before he expired.”

For the final word of the second excerpt, where you guessed ‘magis[tri?]’, the Met book says ‘magius’. This is typographically consistent with luctus in the first line, and eius in the third line of the first excerpt.  In all three words the -us suffixes has been replaced with the same siglum.

@MJD That's a much better translation! I fixed mine. Regarding magius, I'm still confused by the suggestion and translation: is it supposed to be neuter comparative adjective? I can't find any mention of magius in the Packhum classical corpus (except the name Magius) nor in the Corpus Thomisticum. I would have expected magnum or perhaps maius.
